# QGIS 3.30 organize labels with callouts for point-features in a circle around the map center

Tags: labeling, circle, callout, crossing

My hope is to get labels with callouts for a point-layer spreading towards the edges of the canvas.

I thought about

```
make_line (
    $geometry,
    closest_point (
        overlay_nearest (make_circle(  @map_extent_center  ,45))[0],
        $geometry
    )
)
```

but its not working

for use within the print composer

Orientation but not the startpoint should be @map_extent_center (or  @atlas_feature)

How can I achieve this?

[image: map]

Comment: ... and what is the question?